# method returns "infinite" amount of responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing a web application as a proof of my skills. I consider myself a beginner and I stumbled onto weird problem. when I try to return users in a JSON format I get something like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPNIz.png). I kind of loops in the same object over and over again because of the relationships between classess. I can't find a solution to this any help would be greatly appreciated!
[Github link](https://github.com/Kadyen/AccountMonitor)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Account> accounts;
```

The bottom line of the problem is that "@ResponseBody" tries to list Users but encounters "account" property which contains User property and it goes on and on

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In asking questions, it's useful to try to include everything necessary to solving the problem in your question itself (not links).Try putting the minimum necessary snippet of code in your question, including whatever weird output you get.

Comment: I think you've identified the problem correctly, I assume in your database you've got users that link in an infinite circle (i.e. user A references user B, who references user C, ..., who references user A). Is that deliberate? If so, how do you expect the response JSON to look? Do you not want it to include any child users? Or maybe only 1 level?

Comment: yes exactly that's the problem, I'd like my JSON to return only accountId instead of entire account object. Can it be database design problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your are getting cyclic dependencies (of objects) . As you said let's have 2 objects 'users' and 'accounts'. Now 'users' has a 'accounts' object in which their is again 'users' object (mappings i presume). Now whenever you use @ResponseBody, it searches for all the possible getters to fetch the object .
To tackle this you can do two things...

1. Put @JsonIgnore on 'users' object in Accounts class or other way round.
2. Use [@JsonView](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) on your rest controller.

Comment: I put @JsonIgnore for now and I think I'm gonna stick with it.